# Sort TreeMap based on values?

Tags: java, android

I have a TreeMap that holds the following keys/values:

```
    private ArrayList<TreeMap<String,String>> mList = new ArrayList<TreeMap<String,String>>();
    TreeMap<String,String> item = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    item.put("FirstName", strFirstName);  
    item.put("LastName", strLastName);
    item.put("Country", strCountry);
    mList.add( item );
```

How can I sort the TreeMap by the *values* stored under the "LastName" key after adding all the items? I would like to have a TreeMap in the same format as the original list but with the mentioned sorting applied:

"James", "Amish", "USA"
"Charles", "Brentwood", "USA"
"Jake", "Cornell", "USA"
"Amy", "Dunn", "USA"
"Melinda", "Ellis", "Canada"

I've found a similar question relating to sorting a TreeMap by values in 'regular' Java, but the code didn't work for me - I don't know if because of Android pecularities or my inability to adapt it to fit my needs :-/

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: There's nothing special about Android that should prevent you from sorting a TreeMap.  Post your sorting code so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Why don't you create an object that has these attributes and store it in the ArrayList? Using a TreeMap for this is awfully expensive.

Comment: Also - "The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface." if you are using a comparator to determine sort value it uses that for map.contains() as well and skips your equals/hash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to sort the **ArrayList** containing the TreeMaps, correct?
If so, the following should suit your needs:

```
Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<TreeMap<String, String>>(){
    public int compare(TreeMap<String, String> left, TreeMap<String, String> right) {
        return left.get("LastName").compareTo(right.get("LastName"));
    }
});
```

It should be noted that the use of a TreeMap to contain a list of name/value pairs is probably not necessary - I would just create a class to hold the values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly! I know that a TreeMap inside a TreeMap isn't a very efficient structure, I originally had something simpler but read that TreeMaps are sorted by default, so I changed both to TreeMaps to see if the values are then sorted, which they obviously weren't :-)! Now I can change it back! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not programmed for android, but I do not think there are any diferences. A TreeMap is always sorted, in fact if it cannot sort something it will throw an `exception`. Anyway since you are using String they will be sorted by `natural` order, which is really just a fancy word for the actual implementation of `Comparable` on the `String` class, which just sorts alphabetically.

If you want it to sort it in any other way, there is a constructor of `TreeMap` that receives a `Comparator`, in which there is only one method to implement which is `compare`, here you can specify the desired sorting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: see my comment on the question - TreeMap uses that comparitor to determine map.contains() which is in my opinion kind of nasty

Comment: @Dstarh I didn't know that, but I can see how that can be a problem.

Comment: totally, in my opinion it makes treemap not worth using

Answer (score 0):

It would be wrong to sort a TreeMap by values when the keys are what are compared. If you want a List that is sorted use TreeSet rather then TreeMap.